# How to find IDs with multiple values in other column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database where most customers have a specific unchanging value in another column. I'm trying to find those customer for which this is not true.

```
+----------+--------------+--------------+
| customer | usually_same | usually_diff |
+----------+--------------+--------------+
| 1        | a            | gwer2134     |
| 1        | a            | 1easdsdc     |
| 1        | a            | 123qwerwsg   |
| 1        | b            | czxdadt3     |
| 2        | c            | asd132       |
| 2        | c            | 534t1df      |
| 2        | c            | y56u42       |
+----------+--------------+--------------+
```

I'm trying to get the following

```
+----------+--------------+--------------+
| customer | usually_same | usually_diff |
+----------+--------------+--------------+
| 1        | a            | gwer2134     |
| 1        | a            | 1easdsdc     |
| 1        | a            | 123qwerwsg   |
| 1        | b            | czxdadt3     |
+----------+--------------+--------------+
```

because only id 1 has more than one unique value in `usually_same`. What I'm trying to achieve is very basic. The reason why I'm ending up only with rows with customer 1 is because only customer 1 has 2 distinct values (a and b) for `usually_same`.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable as t1
    WHERE (                  
    SELECT t2.customer                  
    FROM mytable as t2             
    WHERE t2.customer = t1.customer
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t2.usually_same) > 1)
```

Comment: I don't understand the logic here.  Can you better explain how we end up with your expected output?

Comment: What is your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: You query looks fine, Is there any other issue you are facing ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EXISTS` as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable as t1
    WHERE exists (                  
    SELECT 1                  
    FROM mytable as t2             
    WHERE t2.customer = t1.customer
      and t2.usually_same <> t1.usually_same)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this includes rows with ids that have only one distinct ```usually_same``` value. I've just made a minor edit to your and my query. Perhaps this broke it?

Comment: May be. I am not sure. but you can use exists to check if for same ID there exists any record with the different `usually_same`

Comment: I understand, I'm currently trying to test whether this code gives me the table I'm looking for.